# how to get sequence generated ids from batch insert for spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: jdbctemplate

If I have a batch of rows to insert where each row gets a sequence generated id, how can I get those ids (or at least the last one) back when using JdbcTemplate?

E.g., for a single row, I know I use, among other ways

```
jdbcTemplate.update(PreparedStatementCreator, KeyHolder);
```

But there seems to be no correlating batchUpdate method with a KeyHolder parameter.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423815/is-there-anyway-to-get-the-generated-keys-when-using-spring-jdbc-batchupdate

Comment: Thanks.. essentially, you can't.  fiddle.